# A name needed related to $\frac23$

Tags: terminology

I'm working on a problem that many solutions are located at about $\frac23$ of the whole interval $[a,b]\approx[0,N]$, but no solution is close to $\frac13$ of it. I'd like a name for this type of solutions. Now I have

ternary solutions

trichotomy solutions

Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It reminds me of [Cantor's set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Comment: ...and what is " the interval $\;[a,b]\;$" , anyway?

Comment: It is roughly $[0,N]$

Comment: ...and what is the interval $[0,N]$?

Comment: Integers. If $N=3k$ the solutions are something like $2k-1$, $2k$, etc..

Comment: @HaoranChen Let $C=\{x: |x-2N/3|\ll$ a suitable bound$\}$ and use $C$ thereafter